Where to find lookback options example？
I am a beginner in lookback options and I want to learn about real-world examples of this type of over-the-counter option. Where can I find practical examples? Thank you very much!

Lookback options were invented and are discussed in a theoretical setting. I do not think they were ever really traded. Sometimes I have seen their value used as an upper bound or lower bound for other options or strategies. I have heard there is no real interest in trading them, no "problem" that they are a "solution" for. Or at least no one has come up with one.

@nbbo2 Thank you very  much! QAQ
